What is the convention in Mexico for how two last names should be presented on a birth certificate?
I hope this doesn't sound like a personal legal issue, as I know that's generally not allowed here, but I am asking in general terms whether Mexico has a conventional system for how a first and second last name should be listed for each parent on a birth certificate. While I won't go into specifics as to why I am asking this, it is sufficient to say that there is a mismatch that needs to be corrected.
For example, if parent's name was Diego Garcia-Hernandez, Garcia is Diego's father's first last name, and Hernandez is Diego's mother's first last name.
But now let's say that Diego's mother's second last name is Velasquez, coming from Diego's mother's mother's first or second last name.
Which name should be on the birth certificate if one record says Diego Garcia-Hernandez, and another one says diego Garcia-Velasquez, if both last names are listed under Diego's mother's name??

What does this have to do with dual-citizenship? Nothing about citizenship is in the question.
